# Hiding the first table when the second table is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I am trying to drill down to detail rows when a user clicks on a cell in table R.So when a cell is clicked Table L is loaded and Table R has to be hidden . I tried to use $('#RegionTable').hide but it hides the table when it is loaded .but i want it to be hidden only on second click

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function($) {
                    $('#lsearch').click(function(){
                            makeAjaxRequest();
                        });
                    $('form').submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    makeAjaxRequest();
                    return false;
                        }); 

                function makeAjaxRequest() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'php/l_search.php?op=1', 
                        data: {name: $('#l').val()},
                        type: 'get', 
                        success: function(response) { 
                            $('table#R tbody').html(response);
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
             $(document).on('click','#loc_code',function() {
                       var url = $(this).text();
                       url = 'php/l_search.php?op=2&l_code='+url  ;
                       $.ajax({
                        url: url, 
                        type: 'get', 
                        success: function(response) { 
                            $('table#L tbody').html(response);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                    $('#R').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
                        });
</script> `
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
.on('click')
```

do:

```
$('#loc_code').dblclick(function(){
```

https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: Or if you want 1-click to load and the 2nd click to hide etc. you can update the .on('click' code from the success: event or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

actually I used $("#R").hide(); and it works